# Linq To Text that supports Updating the source

Tags: .net, linq

I'm after a method to be able to Query and Modify a text file. I found this sample which is what i am after to query the lines but whats the best way to modify a value on that line and submit it back to the file.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericwhite/archive/2006/08/31/734383.aspx

I would love it if there was something like LinqToSQL's SubmitChanges method you can call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Linq does not mix well with modification - in this case especially not because you cannot read from a text file and write to it at the same time.

What you could do instead is produce a modified output as you iterate over the source and write this output to either a temporary file or memory. Once you have completed iteration over the source (and closed the source file!) you can then copy the temp file to the original file or write the memory enumeration to disk.